# Extract a .TAR file within a .gz file

Tags: python, tar, gzip

I have to untar around fifty *.gz files in a directory. Inside each *.gz file there is a *.TAR file and some other files.
I am trying a python script which extracts the contents of the *.gz files to a directory. But, I am not able to extract the *.TAR files inside the same directory to which the contents of *.gz are extracted.
This is how the script looks:

```
import tarfile
import os
import glob
basedir = "path_to _dir"
for i in glob.glob(basedir +"*.gz"):
  a = os.path.basename(i)
  b = os.path.splitext(a)[0]
  c = os.path.splitext(b)[0]
  os.mkdir(os.path.join(basedir,c))
  t1 = tarfile.open(i)
  t1.extractall(c)
     for j in os.listdir(c):
       if j.endswith('.TAR'):
       print(j)
       t2 = tarfile.open(j)
       t2.extractall()
       t2.close() 
  t1.close()
```

Its giving me the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./untar.py", line 16, in <module>
    t2 = tarfile.open(j)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1660, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1722, in gzopen
    fileobj = bltn_open(name, mode + "b")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0299_0108060501.TAR'
```

0299_0108060501.TAR is the file contained inside the *.gz file

It seems to me that I am doing something very wrong fundamentally, but I don't know what.

Comment: Still some example tar file would be in order here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tar.gz` files are TAR archives compressed with gzip one should use

```
t1 = tarfile.open(i, 'r:gz')
```

as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html).

Also, you need to combine the path of the inner file with the directory being inspected, like so:

```
t2 = tarfile.open(os.path.join(c, j))
```

Comment: @mnu did you replace the line opening `i` or `j` as I've made a mistake and it should have been `i`.

Comment: I changed `t2 = tarfile.open(j)` to `t2 = tarfile.open(j, 'r:gz')`

Comment: @mnu I've tested it here and it seems that if only you open `i` with `r:gz` you don't need the inner loop anymore as I believe `gz` files can contain only a single file inside and the `tar` that's inside is extracted in the first go.

Comment: @mnu Ok, the problem in original exception states that file cannot be opened. Perhaps you need to combine the file name with path? `t2 = tarfile.open(os.path.join(c, j))` should do the trick.

Comment: I removed the inner loop and changed the outer loop to open `i` with  `r:gz` , the contents(one `.TAR` file and few `.ASC` files) of the `.gz` file are extracted. But, the contents of the `.TAR` file are not extracted at all. I was trying to use the inner loop to go inside the directory where the contents of `.gz` file are extracted and further extract the contents of `.TAR` file in the same directory.
These are two of the files I have, if you want to test on them: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oopmtL66D950l0RrcS1D8IVKR4W2ROm_?usp=sharing]